# Checking equality of entire enum?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa, enums

I have a chess puzzle game.

I want to set up the wrong squares in an enum.

```
enum 1000H1wrong {11, 13, 15 21, 22};
```

Can I check to see if a number is in the ENTIRE enum 1000H1wrong.

```
if chesssquare == enum 1000H1wrong {        }
```

same as this this:

```
if ((chesssquare == 11) || (chesssquare == 13) || (chesssquare == 15)    || (chesssquare == 21) || (chesssquare == 22)) {      }
```

Comment: `enum` are a C feature, and to the best of my knowledge there's no useful runtime representation provided for you automatically to let you do this sort of thing.

Comment: You can't have an identifier starting from a digit. It's a compile error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use NSArray instead. In order to check if it contains number use:

```
NSArray *1000H1wrong = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @11, @13, @15 @21, @22, nil];
[1000H1wrong containsObject: @(chesssquare) ];
```

Comment: Yes, for a chess board you can just implement a 64 element set as a `uint64_t` and then use normal bitwise operators to test for set membership etc.

Comment: You can't have an identifier starting from a digit. It's a compile error

Comment: To be fair, for using a chess square, two ints sound like an easier representation than a 64-valued enumeration.

Comment: Actually it is for chesspuzzles....  Chezzles!!  Check out appbackr, if you want to see game.  But thanks so much for the answer.  Appreciate it.  This site is great

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic way to check for membership in a series of enumerated values. You can place them into an NSSet as giorasch recommends. But my preference would be to use a straight C array:

```
static int squares1001H1wrong[] = {11, 13, 15, 21, 22};

#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

static BOOL isInSquares1001H1wrong(int square)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(squares1001H1wrong); ++i)
        if (squares1001H1wrong[i] == square)
            return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

The array is constructed at compile-time, not run-time. No objects are constructed. The test is made without a single method invocation.

Objective-C is a superset of the C language. Learn C to gain access the full power of Objective-C. For an example of avoiding an NSArray of NSDictionary elements, see [Objective-C Is Still C (Not Java!)](https://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-is-c/)